# Firestore, Array vs documents list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Assuming a user has a thousand friends, but when calling a friend list on a specific screen, bringing in a thousand documents is expensive and time consuming. Even if pagination is performed, there will be a speed delay due to additional requests.

And according to the official documentation, you can put 1MB in documents, that is, about 1 million characters. However, what I worry about when using Arrays is that there will be situations where things get complicated in many ways.

Are there any exact standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be fully aware of the limitations of Firestore in this case.  There is no new information that will help you here.

If you have a list of things to store in Firestore, and that list could exceed the max size of a document (1MB, as you correctly state), then you are going to have a problem.  On the other hand, if you put all of those items in other documents, you're going to have to pay for all of those reads.  That's the tradeoff -- you will have to decide which problem is worse.  Typically, people choose to use separately document so they are limited by the size of a document.  But that's your call to make.

You could try to shard that list across multiple documents somehow, but that will add much complexity to your code.  Again, your call to make.

Comment: It seems to be a difficult choice! haha Doug Stevenson, Thank you all the time. wish you always with good luck

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about the "sharding" option... 

For example, have a `friends` collection, which will be list of documents that contain arrays of friends.  

After reaching 1MB when writing to a document, Firebase may return a size limit reached error.  

If so, create a new document in the collection, which also has a friends array.  

So then to read, instead of getting one document, we query the collection.  However then we also have issues with updating documents, sorting, searching, etc.

But then